# Why is the performance of reverse O(n^2) in Scheme?

Tags: list, scheme, lisp

Let's say my reverse function in Scheme is coded in the following way:

```
(define (reversee lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (append (reversee (cdr lst)) (list (car lst)))))
```

Why is the performance of this procedure O(n^2)?

Comment: The append combined with your reversee function is essentially a nested loop.

Comment: Short answer: because you're using `append`, you should use `cons` to write an `O(n)` solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, consider what the function has to do:

- for a zero-element list it just returns the list.
- for a 1 element list it appends the reverse of a zero element list and the first element.
- for a 2 element list it appends the reverse of a 1 element list and the first element
- ... and so on.

It's obvious from this that to reverse an n-element list it calls itself recursively n times.  So this looks like the time complexity is O(n), right?

Not so fast: for each recursive call it *appends* two lists.  So we need to worry about the complexity of `append`.  Well, let's write the best `append` we can:

```
(define (my-append l1 l2)
  (if (null? l1)
      l2
      (cons (car l1) (my-append (cdr l1) l2))))
```

OK, so what's the complexity of this?  First of all, only depends on the length of `l1`, so we only need to worry about that:

- if `l1` is a zero-element list it returns `l2`
- if l2 is a 1-element list is conses its first element onto the result of appending the rest of it to `l2`
- ... and so on

So to append an n-element list to some other list there are n steps.  So what is the time complexity of each of these steps?  Well, it's constant: `cons` and `cdr` and `car` take constant time.  So the time complexity of `append` is the length of the first list.

So this means that the time complexity of your reverse function is

n + n-1 + n-2 + ... + 1

It's a famous result that the value of such a sum is n(n+1)/2 (you do get this result by writing it as ((n + 1) + (n - 1 + 2) + ... (1 + n))/2 = ((n + 1) + ... (n + 1))/2 with n terms in the sum.  So the complexity is n(n+1), which is asymptotically equal to n^2.

There is a better version of `reverse`, of course.

Answer (score 3):

A more readable and understandable O(N) `reverse`....

```lisp
(define (reverse lst)
  (let reverser ((lst lst)
                 (reversed '()))
    (if (null? lst)
        reversed
        (reverser (cdr lst) (cons (car lst) reversed)))))

(reverse '(1 2 3))
```

By building up the reversed list as it goes with a tail-recursive approach, it only has to traverse the list once.